# Pentaho shell throwing an error while I am calling API to download a file

Tags: bash, curl, sh, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho. I want to use curl command in Pentaho Shell to call API and download a file. The file is getting downloading but it is throwing some error message while it is downloading.

- Drag the 'shell' step into transformation window
- Edit the step.
- Check insert script and give working directory.
- In the script window give the curl command to call API.

Script is [just a curl command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKbXJ.png)

The error message is [on shell window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ghy.png)
How can we avoid the error message?

Comment: Having the same issue, but with a script that called wget -> were you able to find any answer?

Comment: nope...still the same

Comment: I get the same error messages when downloading files via Pentaho with WGET/CURL. It does download the file though. The error does not stop my transformation/job either, so its more of an annoying UX problem. Are you also able to download the files?